# Can we suggest tag edits? There is error in a tag I wrote

Tags: support

There appears to be no way to edit a tag, at least with my level of privilege. The other day I wrote a tag (which was soon approved), and today I noticed an error.  Could someone either tell me how I could suggest an edit to it, or edit it for me?  The tag is [tsuki-ga-kirei](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tsuki-ga-kirei).

**it ends with**

> being third-years in middle school [eighth grade].

**it should say**

> being third-years in middle school [ninth graders in American English].

The main reason is to correct an error of fact, but the other words, and shift from *grade* to *graders*, is to improve context and match agreement between preceding and bracketed text.

Comment: @AkiTanaka Duh! [slaps face] Thanks. I was so focused on searching for the word **edit**, my mind didn't bother parsing that phrase. Anyway, I have "improved tag info" now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select/search for a specific tag, there's an info box on the top with its excerpt and some links. Instead of "edit", one of the link is "improve tag info".

> [image: improve tag info]

From there, you can (suggest an) edit the tag excerpt and/or tag wiki.